# How to set up the Tor browser on Linux Mint in a VM with a VPN on the Host

Tags: windows, linux, vpn, tor, windows-10

(Forgive me, I don't know whether to post this here for in the "Tor" community)

I'm brand new to Tor, I understand the basics of how it works and the Do's & Don'ts. I have a Windows 10 computer (Fully up to date) with Virtual Box installed. Within the VB I have Linux Mint installed, set up and ready to go. I have also downloaded the Tor browser from the official website. However, when I boot the browser it asks me if I want to just connect and go, or if I want to configure the browser if I have a VPN running. Thing is my Host Windows 10 system has ProtonVPN installed and active. So my question is do I need to configure the Tor browser even though the VPN is on the host? If I do need to configure it, how do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon how your VM is connected to the Internet. Generally there are two options: NAT or BRIDGED.

NAT will use whatever your Host is using, including a host VPN if present.

Bridged will set up a second native connection as if the host were not present.

In either case you want to "Just Connect".

Although there are a few reasons for tunneling Tor through a VPN, they all relate to locally hiding the fact that you are running Tor. It does not substantially add to security or anonymity over running Tor directly.

Comment: I am currently running the VM through NAT. Yes, my goal is to hide the Tor from my ISP.

Comment: That's fine. Some ISPs may try to block Tor, this is more common in repressive countries. Contrary to Hollywood Movies depicting "The Dark Net" (*dun* *dun* *dun*), Tor was originally developed by The US Naval Research Lab and serves very important purposes around the world.

Comment: So just to clarify, I can have the host running the VPN and on Tor in my VM just hit connect? No setup required?

Comment: A VPN does not hide the fact that Tor is used. Tor sends data in bursts of 514 bytes but VPNs do not do any padding, so any VPN sending data in 514 byte bursts has Tor running under it.